# How are the rear headrests in a 2010 Ford Fusion removed?

Tags: ford, interior, fusion

The rear headrests can be raised only to a certain point. Pushing in the adjustment button on the driver side rail does not allow for them to be pulled completely out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there is a pinhole on the passenger side rail/rod (see photo below).

Procedure:

1. Raise the headrest as high as it will go.
2. The headrest must then be lowered *slightly* until it clicks into the topmost groove.  (This step is crucial)
3. Insert a paperclip like object into the passenger side pinhole *and* press in the button on the other rail.
4. While holding in both the pinhole and button, raise the headrest up to remove it.

   [image: 2010 Fusion rear headrest removal pinhole]